# how to write a class with an attribute, and when new an object, this attribute can self-increase

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a student class with an id attribute

when I new objects like this:

```
var s1 = new Student()
var s2 = new Student()
var s3 = new Student()
```

I can get this result:

```
console.log(s1.id) //1
console.log(s2.id) //2
console.log(s3.id) //3
```

Comment: how do you assign the id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Student = (function() {
    var id = 0;

    return function Student() {
        this.id = ++id;
    };
})();
```

Here every new `Student` object will get an incremented `id` from the `var id` that is  in the outer IIFE.

---

The IIFE part isn't strictly needed, but it protects the `var id` from being accidentally modified by other code. Without the IIFE, it would simply be:

```
var id = 0;

function Student() {
    this.id = ++id;
}
```

But the `var id` can be reached by any code in the enclosing scope, so the first example is safer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with either a global variable or a static variable (The latter is preferred). This means that the variable belongs to the type rather than the instance.

```
function Student(){ 
    this.id = Student.currentId;
    Student.currentID++;
}
Student.currentID = 1;
```

Comment: still exposes the variable globally. @cookie monster answer is correct because of the closure.

Comment: @cgatian: Which is not a problem when properly namespaced on `Student`… Nobody said it would need to be private.

Comment: @cgatian I didn't think it mattered because it was part of the `Student` object, but if you prefer, go with @cookiemonster.